# cannot find symbol method ParseInt(java.lang.String) class java.lang.Integer int id=Integer.ParseInt(data); ^

Tags: java

```
class BufferedReaderEx
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter student id :");
        String data=br.readLine();
        int id=Integer.ParseInt(data);
        System.out.println("Enter student name :");
        String name=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a java marks  :");
        String data2=br.readLine();
        int cm=Integer.ParseInt(data2);
        System.out.println("Enter a oracle marks  :");
        String data3=br.readLine();
        int om=Integer.ParseInt(data3);
        System.out.println(" total marks is ="+(cm+om));
        System.out.println("Student details : ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        System.out.println("id "+id+"\t\t\t"+"name "+name+"\t\t\t"+"total marks "+(cm+om));}}
```

Comment: Please format your code. Its `parseInt` BTW

Comment: For future reference, please read the Help Centre page [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

First things first: you know there are better ways to post code here, don't you?

Now to your problem:
Even you haven't really asked a question, i will provide an answer that might be correct to your non-existent question which i guessed by reading the title and the provided code.
I read it as "Where does this error message come from and how can i fix it?"
As you may have already noticed, Java uses lowerCamelCase for its methods, which is your error here, because you used UpperCamelCase for `Integer.ParseInt(java.lang.String)` which should be `Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String)`

Comment: Even though you have seriously made an effort, your answer comes out somewhat passive-aggressive, I think. There is no harm in being kind while also being right.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am naturally passive-aggressive, even if not necessary. I will try to change that for future answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `Integer.ParseInt(data1)`

To

`Integer.parseInt(data1)`

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the method.

Use   **`parseInt`**   not `ParseInt`

```
package com.example.input;

import java.io.*;

class BufferedReaderEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter student id :");
        String data = br.readLine();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(data);
        System.out.println("Enter student name :");
        String name = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a java marks  :");
        String data2 = br.readLine();
        int cm = Integer.parseInt(data2);
        System.out.println("Enter a oracle marks  :");
        String data3 = br.readLine();
        int om = Integer.parseInt(data3);
        System.out.println(" total marks is =" + (cm + om));
        System.out.println("Student details : ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        System.out.println("id " + id + "\t\t\t" + "name " + name + "\t\t\t"
                + "total marks " + (cm + om));
    }
}
```